# Add a Class to an existing div element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to display an icon for the my account section right next to the cart icon (Woocommerce).

In order to do that I would like to add another class with the name "et-account-info" to an existing div id element. The HTML-code looks like this:

```
<div id="et-top-navigation">
    <nav id="top-menu-nav">…</nav>
    <a href="https://example.com/cart/" class="et-cart-info">…</a>
    <div id="et_mobile_nav_menu"></div>
</div>
```

Eventually it should look something like this. The new class should be displayed right below the first a tag.

```
<div id="et-top-navigation">
    <nav id="top-menu-nav">…</nav>
    <a href="https://example.com/cart/" class="et-cart-info">…</a>
    <a href="https://example.com/my-account/" class="et-account-info">…</a>
    <div id="et_mobile_nav_menu"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using a Javascript function which did not work at all:

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("et-top-navigation");
element.classList.add("et-account-info");
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is not working? Or is there a smoother way using php?

Comment: This looks like that you would like to add a new element as a whole rather than the class if i see the second code snippet.

Do you want to add this element -

'<a href="https://example.com/my-account/" class="et-account-info">…</a>'

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? Why not edit the templat directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are adding the script in the `<head></head>` tag. Unfortunatly scripts added like this will run before the rest of the document has been loaded/parsed. You need to tell your code to wait for the DOM to be fully loaded and parsed before checking for the element.

```js
function addClassToElement() {
    var element = document.getElementById("et-top-navigation");
    element.classList.add("et-account-info");
}

// Check if document is already loaded. If so, run the function.
// Otherwise, wait for the DOMContentLoaded event to fire before running it.
if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
    addClassToElement();
} else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addClassToElement);
}
```

However, your code is incomplete according to the outcome you are looking for. This will just add a class to the `div` element with ID `et-top-navigation`.

Have a go at adding (hint: appending) the new element you are looking to add.